# C# How to make a var + 1 per one loop

Tags: c#, loops, encryption

I have a problem making an encryption programm for school. The excersice is, making a encryption programm that's is capable of encrypten plain text such as ".txt" files to a personal passw. In my case it's my birthday "0811200"
So for an example, your sentence start's with an "a" the encrypted char should be "a" because the first zero in my personal passw stands for zero steps in the alphabet and 8 means 8 steps in the alfabet and so on.

I already made the encryption but that's only work on the first 8 chars of the text, so my problem is. Can I loop the entire code so I can decrypt my text? In the pictures below you can see what i mean!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSWxN.jpg

And here is the code what I have already:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button3.Enabled = true;
  {
      foreach (char a in textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1))
      foreach (char b in textBox1.Text.Substring(1, 1))
      foreach (char c in textBox1.Text.Substring(2, 1))
      foreach (char d in textBox1.Text.Substring(3, 1))
      foreach (char z in textBox1.Text.Substring(4, 1))
      foreach (char f in textBox1.Text.Substring(5, 1))
      foreach (char g in textBox1.Text.Substring(6, 1))
      foreach (char h in textBox1.Text.Substring(7, 1))
      {
          char encrypted1 = (char)(a + 0);
          textBox2.Text += encrypted1.ToString();
          char encrypted2 = (char)(b + 8);
          textBox2.Text += encrypted2.ToString();
          char encrypted3 = (char)(c + 1);
          textBox2.Text += encrypted3.ToString();
          char encrypted4 = (char)(d + 1);
          textBox2.Text += encrypted4.ToString();
          char encrypted5 = (char)(z + 2);
          textBox2.Text += encrypted5.ToString();
          char encrypted6 = (char)(f + 0);
          textBox2.Text += encrypted6.ToString();
          char encrypted7 = (char)(g + 0);
          textBox2.Text += encrypted7.ToString();
          char encrypted8 = (char)(h + 0);
          textBox2.Text += encrypted8.ToString();
      }
  }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (char a in textBox2.Text.Substring(0, 1))
  foreach (char b in textBox2.Text.Substring(1, 1))
  foreach (char c in textBox2.Text.Substring(2, 1))
  foreach (char d in textBox2.Text.Substring(3, 1))
  foreach (char z in textBox2.Text.Substring(4, 1))
  foreach (char f in textBox2.Text.Substring(5, 1))
  foreach (char g in textBox2.Text.Substring(6, 1))
  foreach (char h in textBox2.Text.Substring(7, 1))
  {
      char encrypted1 = (char)(a - 0);
      textBox3.Text += encrypted1.ToString();
      char encrypted2 = (char)(b - 8);
      textBox3.Text += encrypted2.ToString();
      char encrypted3 = (char)(c - 1);
      textBox3.Text += encrypted3.ToString();
      char encrypted4 = (char)(d - 1);
      textBox3.Text += encrypted4.ToString();
      char encrypted5 = (char)(z - 2);
      textBox3.Text += encrypted5.ToString();
      char encrypted6 = (char)(f - 0);
      textBox3.Text += encrypted6.ToString();
      char encrypted7 = (char)(g - 0);
      textBox3.Text += encrypted7.ToString();
      char encrypted8 = (char)(h - 0);
      textBox3.Text += encrypted8.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: A `Substring()` with second argument (length!) of `1` returns exactly 1 `char`. So, what do you need all those `foreach`es for! They don't iterate anything, there is only one char in each of their "sequences". Why not simply `char encrypted1 = textBox2.Text[0] - 0; char encrypted2 = textBox2.Text[1] - 8;` etc

Comment: `Substring(n, 1)` is going to return a string with a length of 1. So you're using a `for...each` to iterate over the characters in a string when there will only be one character. Think of it like a `for` loop that starts with one and ends with one. You don't need a loop when there's only one of something.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guide on posting code - so far it is clear that you have not tried to produce minimal sample demonstrating the problem you have...

Comment: Based on a glance at your algorithm: Your life will be much easier if you break this down into pieces. Why not a method that returns the encoded or decoded char given a char? Since your encryption is symmetric the same method can be used with a flag I think. Then you just call this in a loop over your cryptotext or plaintext string. Then the only thing that you need to solve is how to make your key work for other parts of the alphabet. Hint: modulo math is one technique for this. You could also make a 26-char key by concatenating the key, which is cruftier but should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all those strange loops. You want to loop through the input text and then change the character according to it's position:

```
//Encoding:
string passwd = "08112000";
int pos = 0;
string result = string.Empty;
foreach(char c in textBox1.Text)
{
    result += ((char)(c - passwd[pos % passwd.Length])).ToString();
    pos++;
}
textBox2.Text = result;
```

Via the modulo (`%`) you always iterate from `0` to `passwd.Lenght - 1` to take the correct "encryption" letter.

(In general it's better to use a `StringBuilder` or concatination instead of `result +=`, but in this case it's micro-optimization).

---

You can shorten this code with LINQ:

```
string passwd = "08112000";
textBox2.Text = new String(textBox1.Text.Select((c, index) => (char)(c - passwd[index % passwd.Length])).ToArray());
```

Comment: If I want to decrypt the encrypted code, can I just simply change the "-" to "+"? Thanks for replying quick!

Comment: @RalfOfzo yes (and of course change the textboxes respectivly).

Comment: I have tried it by changing the "-" to "+" but the only thing I get is more random rumbers. See pic below: https://imgur.com/a/SDIlq

Comment: @RalfOfzo I forgot the cast to `char`, so it was treaded as `int`. should work now (I tested the LINQ version).

Comment: What do you mean? Do I need to replace the int to char?

Comment: @RalfOfzo I updated the answer: the mistake was at `result += ((char)(c-...`, the cast (`(char)`) was missing. Same in the linq version.

Comment: I only get some random characters:( the "a" should be an "a" in the picture below but it doen't. Thank your for helping me:) http://prntscr.com/i4k4dk

Comment: @RalfOfzo That seems fine to me, decoding works to. The random characters come from the white space in your source text. That white space is a character with ordinal 32 (0x20). If you subtract e.g. `8`, you have a character that's not part of an alphabet, or worse, a control character. But that is a general problem of your algorithm. To fix that you would need a completely different algorithm or to simply don't en-/decode certain magic values. But that's a different question not answerable in comments.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I combined to answers together and I found the solution see pic below:http://prntscr.com/i4kfa0

Answer (score 0):

Those loops are bizarre. I think you just want

```
textBox3.Test = "";
foreach(char c in textBox1.Text)
{
     char encrypted1 = (char)(c - 0);
     textBox3.Text += encrypted1.ToString();
}
```

Separate question is whether or not this is the correct 'encryption ' mechanism, but at least the code is readable. And it will deal with any length

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some `linq` code:

```
var text = "Kies bestand";
var codes = new[] {0, 8, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0};

var encrypted = new string(text.Select((c, i) => 
  (char) (c + codes[i % codes.Length])).ToArray());

var decrypted = new string(encrypted.Select((c, i) => 
  (char)(c - codes[i % codes.Length])).ToArray());
```

Comment: hint: there already is a `Select` overload that gives you the index of the current element. So no need to zip it against another int-range.

Comment: @RenéVogt really sad that I forgot about that overload. Thanks!